# When I know $a+b+c, a^2+a^2+b^2, a^3+b^3+c^3$, then how can I find the $a$ and $b$ and $ c$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

When I know

$$a+b+c = A$$
$$a^2+a^2+b^2 = B $$
$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = C$$

Then how can I find the $a$ and $b$ and $c$?

Comment: This question has been asked before many times [for example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240517/newtons-sum-help)

Comment: Notice that, more generally, [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) provides a systematic way to obtain $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ as roots of a polynomial from the first $n$ power sums.

Comment: A question asking for the general method [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378944/inverting-power-sum-of-symmetric-polynomial?rq=1).

Comment: Other special cases: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/three-variable-system-of-simultaneous-equations/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278394/find-numbers-a-b-c-given-that-abc-12-a2b2c2-50-and-a3b3c3?lq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $$a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)$$  to find $ab+bc+ca=P$

and $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\{(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)\}$$ to find $abc=Q$

Then $a,b,c$ are the roots of $$t^3-At^2+Pt-Q=0$$