# Find all integer for triplets$(a,b,c)$ [detail]

Tags: number-theory

Find all integer   for  triplets$(a,b,c)$  that

$a+b+c =3$

$a+b^2+c^2=17$

and $a^2 +b^3+c^3 =21$

I have try to start with

$17-a =   ( 3-a   )^{2} - 2bc
 \ \ $ and  $21-a^2 =   (3-a)\left ((17-a) -  bc  \right ) +3abc$

but It seems to not be working for me. Could you please guide me any brilliant solution for this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Dietrich, note that the current question asks about $a+b^2+c^2$, not $a^2+b^2+c^2$, and about $a^2+b^3+c^3$, not $a^3+b^3+c^3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, corrected. It looked so similar to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792608/when-i-know-abc-a2a2b2-a3b3c3-then-how-can-i-find-the-a-and?noredirect=1&lq=1), I am sorry.

Answer (score 2):

From the first two equations, you get $14=(b^2-b)+(c^2-c)$, from which you get $58=(2b-1)^2+(2c-1)^2$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: how do you get to the last equation you  listed in your answer?

Comment: Guessing that factorize out (e.g. 4b^2 - 4b + 1) which combine every single term from first two question.

Comment: @poe, you multiply both sides by 4, add 2 to both sides, and factor.